# Hazelcast logs "No backup record found for call" occationally

Tags: logging, hazelcast

I just upgraded our production system to Hazelcast 3.0.1 (from 2.5). After the upgrade, we are experiencing a lot of WARNs in the logs saying the following:

```
[<ip>]:10102 [dev] No backup record found for call[148681]!
```

They appear approximately 30 times per day, and this compares to around 100.000 to 500.000 distributed map accesses each day. Which means this just happens occationally.

I've tried to understand why these warnings comes, but have had no luck. They are logged from the class OperationServiceImpl, on line 568, which looks like this:

```
@PrivateApi
void notifyBackupCall(long callId) {
    final Semaphore lock = backupCalls.get(callId);
    if (lock == null) {
        logger.warning("No backup record found for call[" + callId + "]!");
    } else {
        lock.release();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what the cause of this warning is, and how to fix it? I don't just want to silence the logger, I want to know the root cause of this.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I'm also looking at the code.

Do you know if members are added/removed (so repartitioning is happening) during the day? Because that could be the cause; because the lock (the semaphore) is not moved with the partition. So it could happen that notifyBackup is done on the new partition owner, while the lock is stored the old partition owner (it will not be moved).

Comment: No members were added or removed. We have a fairly stable cluster, so that can't be the problem. But I combined the upgrade to 3.0 with the introduction of using locks and Topics, so I don't really know if this is caused by the upgrade or if it is introduced because of the locks/topics (before, I just used distributed maps)

Comment: Ok, then that is not the cause. 

I need to ask Mehmet, since he knows exactly how this part works and what could be the cause.